# Como hago para que la division de 2 enteros se muestre como un numero con sus digitos en JAVA

Tags: java

< double anioB =0;
   anioB = subtotal/1461;
   System.out.println(String.format("%.3f", anioB));

// **tira 503.000   con subtotal 734952  y en realidad tendria que ser 
     503.0472....**>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede porque los ordenadores trabajan en binario y a la hora de trabajar con variables de tipo `float` o `double` cometen errores de precisión al trabajar con valores que no pueden representar.Por ejemplo, si queremos representar 1/3, el resultado es 0.3333333333333… y así hasta el infinito. No podemos dar un valor exacto a esa operación. Java nos proporciona `BigDecimal` una clase pensada para resolver este tipo de problemas.

```
BigDecimal resul, num, den;
//Divide num/den con una escala decimal 5 con el método de redondeo CEILING
resul = num.divide(den, 5, RoundingMode.CEILING)
System.out.println(resul.toString());
```

Comment: <<<  Gracias. Me imagine que tendria que importar una libreria. Como es un ejercicio estaba tratando de hacer lo mayor posible para no importar librerias, muy pero muy dificil, dado que es sumar 2 fechas. Imaginen la de calculos para simular un calendario sin importaciones SOLO con lang una odisea GRACIAS AS13L >>>

Comment: Respuesta incorrecta. Está haciendo la división entera y por eso redondea  a 0. Luego asigna a un `double`, pero el valor ya es incorrecto. Los `float` y `double` tienen precisión limitada pero no TAN limitada.